# Cannot feed value of shape (200, 40) for Tensor u'rnn_cell_40/Tanh:0', which has shape '(200, 4)'

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

this is my code, when I run it, I cannot understand the error, why `u'rnn_cell_40/Tanh:0` need feed value?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import reader
raw_data = reader.ptb_raw_data('simple-examples/data')
train_data, val_data, test_data, num_classes = raw_data
batch_size = 200
num_steps = 40

def build_graph(num_steps,
            bptt_steps = 20, batch_size = 200, num_classes = num_classes,
            state_size = 4, embed_size = 50, learning_rate = 0.01):
    g = tf.get_default_graph()

    x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, None], name='input_placeholder')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch_size, None], name='labels_placeholder')
    default_init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])
    init_state = tf.placeholder_with_default(default_init_state,
                                             [batch_size, state_size], name='state_placeholder')
    dropout = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [], name='dropout_placeholder')

    x_one_hot = tf.one_hot(x, num_classes)
    x_as_list = [tf.squeeze(i, squeeze_dims=[1]) for i in tf.split(x_one_hot, num_steps, 1)]

    with tf.variable_scope('embeddings'):
        embeddings = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix', [num_classes, embed_size])

    def embedding_lookup(one_hot_input):
        with tf.variable_scope('embeddings', reuse=True):
            embeddings = tf.get_variable('embedding_matrix', [num_classes, embed_size])
            embeddings = tf.identity(embeddings)
            g.add_to_collection('embeddings', embeddings)
            return tf.matmul(one_hot_input, embeddings)

    rnn_inputs = [embedding_lookup(i) for i in x_as_list]

    rnn_inputs = [tf.nn.dropout(x, dropout) for x in rnn_inputs]

    # rnn_cells
    with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell'):
        W = tf.get_variable('W', [embed_size + state_size, state_size])
        b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

    def rnn_cell(rnn_input, state):
        with tf.variable_scope('rnn_cell', reuse=True):

            W = tf.get_variable('W', [embed_size + state_size, state_size])
            W = tf.identity(W)
            g.add_to_collection('Ws', W)

            b = tf.get_variable('b', [state_size], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
            b = tf.identity(b)
            g.add_to_collection('bs', b)

            return tf.tanh(tf.matmul(tf.concat([rnn_input, state], 1), W) + b)

    state = init_state
    rnn_outputs = []
    for rnn_input in rnn_inputs:
        state = rnn_cell(rnn_input, state)
        print state.name
        rnn_outputs.append(state)

    print init_state.name
    #apply dropout to outputs
    rnn_outputs = [tf.nn.dropout(x, dropout) for x in rnn_outputs]

    final_state = rnn_outputs[-1]
    print final_state.name

    #logits and predictions
    with tf.variable_scope('softmax'):
        W = tf.get_variable('W_softmax', [state_size, num_classes])
        b = tf.get_variable('b_softmax', [num_classes], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    logits = [tf.matmul(rnn_output, W) + b for rnn_output in rnn_outputs]
    predictions = [tf.nn.softmax(logit) for logit in logits]

    #losses
    y_as_list = [tf.squeeze(i, squeeze_dims=[1]) for i in tf.split(y, num_steps, 1)]
    losses = [tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logit,labels=label) \
              for logit, label in zip(logits, y_as_list)]
    total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(losses)

    """
    Implementation of true truncated backprop using TF's high-level gradients function.

    Because I add gradient-ops for each error, this are a number of duplicate operations,
    making this a slow implementation. It would be considerably more effort to write an
    efficient implementation, however, so for testing purposes, it's OK that this goes slow.

    An efficient implementation would still require all of the same operations as the full
    backpropagation through time of errors in a sequence, and so any advantage would not come
    from speed, but from having a better distribution of backpropagated errors.
    """

    embed_by_step = g.get_collection('embeddings')
    Ws_by_step = g.get_collection('Ws')
    bs_by_step = g.get_collection('bs')

    # Collect gradients for each step in a list
    embed_grads = []
    W_grads = []
    b_grads = []

    # Keeping track of vanishing gradients for my own curiousity
    vanishing_grad_list = []

    # Loop through the errors, and backpropagate them to the relevant nodes
    for i in range(num_steps):
        start = max(0,i+1-bptt_steps)
        stop = i+1
        grad_list = tf.gradients(losses[i],
                                 embed_by_step[start:stop] +\
                                 Ws_by_step[start:stop] +\
                                 bs_by_step[start:stop])
        embed_grads += grad_list[0 : stop - start]
        W_grads += grad_list[stop - start : 2 * (stop - start)]
        b_grads += grad_list[2 * (stop - start) : ]

        if i >= bptt_steps:
            vanishing_grad_list.append(grad_list[stop - start : 2 * (stop - start)])

    grad_embed = tf.add_n(embed_grads) / (batch_size * bptt_steps)
    grad_W = tf.add_n(W_grads) / (batch_size * bptt_steps)
    grad_b = tf.add_n(b_grads) / (batch_size * bptt_steps)

    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
    grads_and_vars_tf_style = opt.compute_gradients(total_loss, tf.trainable_variables())
    grads_and_vars_true_bptt = \
        [(grad_embed, tf.trainable_variables()[0]),
         (grad_W, tf.trainable_variables()[1]),
         (grad_b, tf.trainable_variables()[2])] + \
        opt.compute_gradients(total_loss, tf.trainable_variables()[3:])
    train_tf_style = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_tf_style)
    train_true_bptt = opt.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_true_bptt)

    return dict(
        train_tf_style = train_tf_style,
        train_true_bptt = train_true_bptt,
        gvs_tf_style = grads_and_vars_tf_style,
        gvs_true_bptt = grads_and_vars_true_bptt,
        gvs_gradient_check = opt.compute_gradients(losses[-1], tf.trainable_variables()),
        loss = total_loss,
        final_state = final_state,
        x=x,
        y=y,
        init_state=init_state,
        dropout=dropout,
        vanishing_grads=vanishing_grad_list
    )



def reset_graph():
    if 'sess' in globals() and sess:
        sess.close()
    tf.reset_default_graph()


reset_graph()
g = build_graph(num_steps = 40, bptt_steps = 20)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


X, Y = next(reader.ptb_iterator(train_data, batch_size=200, num_steps=40))

gvs_bptt = sess.run(g['gvs_true_bptt'], feed_dict={g['x']:X, g['y']:Y, g['dropout']: 1})
```

this is result:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-a5d0b8513bfb> in <module>()
    205 #     gvs_bptt = sess.run(g['gvs_true_bptt'], feed_dict={g['x']:X, g['y']:Y, g['dropout']: 1})
    206 
--> 207 gvs_bptt = sess.run(g['gvs_true_bptt'], feed_dict={g['x']:X, g['y']:Y, g['dropout']: 1})

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in run(self, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    776     try:
    777       result = self._run(None, fetches, feed_dict, options_ptr,
--> 778                          run_metadata_ptr)
    779       if run_metadata:
    780         proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

/root/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.pyc in _run(self, handle, fetches, feed_dict, options, run_metadata)
    959                 'Cannot feed value of shape %r for Tensor %r, '
    960                 'which has shape %r'
--> 961                 % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
    962           if not self.graph.is_feedable(subfeed_t):
    963             raise ValueError('Tensor %s may not be fed.' % subfeed_t)

ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (200, 40) for Tensor u'rnn_cell_40/Tanh:0', which has shape '(200, 4)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an *init_state* of shape [200, 4] for the RNN cell here:

```
default_init_state = tf.zeros([batch_size, state_size])
```

But you read data in batches of [200, 40], hence:

```
Cannot feed value of shape (200, 40) for Tensor u'rnn_cell_40/Tanh:0', which has shape '(200, 4)'.
```

Where do you exactly split your data-dim by 10? I cannot run your code. But even with dummy data,

```
X = (np.random.randn(batch_size, 4) * 10).astype(np.int32)
Y = (np.random.randn(batch_size, 4) * 10).astype(np.int32)

gvs_bptt = sess.run(g['gvs_true_bptt'], feed_dict={
                    g['x']: X, g['y']: Y, g['dropout']: 1})
```

it gives me:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Shape [200,?] is not fully defined
     [[Node: input_placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_INT32, shape=[200,?], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

My advice is to debug your graph by adding

```
print "tensorname", tensorname.get_shape()
```

to see if your data really has the correct shape.

Comment: data is：
X = (np.random.randn(batch_size, 40) * 10).astype(np.int32)
Y = (np.random.randn(batch_size, 40) * 10).astype(np.int32)